# Is there a YAML config fix for `Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease`

Tags: yaml, circleci, hexo, debian-jessie

I've seen a lot around this issue but so far nothing that works in my circumstance. I have a Hexo blog deployed over CircleCI that had no issues, and without making any changes to my YAML config the build began failing when I pushed updates. Of the existing issue reports and fixes I've seen nothing has worked when applying to my `circle.yml` file, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Many solutions recommend adding some script to update the URL, but I think that's taking me in the wrong direction, and frankly beyond my current knowledge.

During CircleCI's build when it gets to the AWS CLI build:

```
        name: Install AWS CLI
        command: |
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y awscli
```

it completes 6 successful `gets` but then I see:

```
Fetched 10.1 MB in 1s (6749 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Exited with code 100
```

That step previously gave me:
`Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]`

So despite this being well documented, I've struggled to find a solution that works in my Hexo, Node-based setup. If you can teach me something new I'd be much appreciative!

Comment: The Jessie version of Debian has been archived (by Debian) and does not work without adding extra repo URLs (and even then there can be problems). The best fix is to upgrade to the latest stable version of Debian. What executor are you using, and parent image are you using? (This will be in your `config.yml`).

Comment: @halfer I appreciate the reply, I can't really speak towards your questions, I think I just followed an implementation guide into territory that is overkill for my needs and much of what you mention here is in CircleCI's wheelhouse. I'm pivoting to deploy via AWS instead, it's a better fit for this project's needs.